# Is there any word for "small hand written note/letter" in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

In some languages there is a name for a amicable note that you hand write to a lover or to someone to show appreciation, it's not as long and less formal than a letter. does english have an equivalent for that?

Comment: I would just call it a "note". I can't think of anything more specific.

Comment: "Note" has many and varied meanings by context, and the only more specific form of it that I can think of is "memo", which is highly formal and dispassionate. "communique" can carry this meaning, but only when contextualized in a way that would make "note" an appropriate alternative. There are a wealth of descriptors which would be appropriate here, so I don't see the need for such a word unless you're doing translations. If you are translating, it depends largely on the surrounding passage.

Comment: OED **notelet** 1a *A short written message or communication. Now **rare**.*

Comment: I was going to include a link to a picture of a note card - but rediscovered that before handheld computers and phones, students used to create class notes on very specifically designed cards that are also called "note cards".  Because we (modern US society) seems to settle for calling brief, handwritten communications as well as other types of communications "notes", we further emphasize the handwritten aspect as well as the brevity of the communication by describing the action as *"jotting a note"* which almost always is interpreted as the type of note you described.

Comment: I think "personal note" comes closest in a few words.

Comment: The term ***billet-doux***, French for a 'love letter', was, in my recollection, used as recently as the 1950s in English. It has also been used more recently, with irony, to describe a company memo, or some such. In English it is pronounced *billy-doo*.

Comment: +1 for 'billet-doux', though I've only seen used (unironically, at least) to refer to love notes specifically, rather than general platonic admiration or appreciation.

Comment: Note: even though _billet-doux_ is French and means ‘love letter’, it's a far cry from being a French (love) letter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a commonly used phrase borrowed from French.

A [*Billet Doux*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=billet+doux) is a hand written love note.

Frequently pronounced *Billy Doo* when used this way but often pronounced in the French way.

Comment: Nice suggestion,  reference might help: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/billet-doux, http://www.bartleby.com/81/1861.html,

Comment: take it from the Froggy I am, Billet doux means sweet note, and it really is just a little outdated, just a tad sweet and carries respect and love at the same time. Can't do for a sexto for example. Pronunciation is not "Billy doo" but "bee-yay doo".

Comment: @Pierre I've only some idea what *sexto* is (a *sext* [sex-based SMS]?) but please bear in mind that once words are borrowed and Anglicised -- or incorporated into *any* language, not just English -- they lose many original attributes and are assimilated and subject to the rules of the target language. *Billet doux* **is** pronounced *billy doo*.

Answer (score 3):

- **a message**
- **a note,** **a short note**

> - message (noun) A usually short communication transmitted by words, signals, or other means from one person to another. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/message)
> - note (noun)  "a brief informal letter" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/note)

You could say "I'm sending her **a note of appreciation**".

Answer (score 3):

[***missive***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/missive)

I've actually never used it before and my impression is I mostly hear it in clichéd phrases. Wiktionary considers it *formal* and defines it thus:

> A written message; a letter, note or memo.

Answer (score -1):

You could go with **scribble**. Though it might give the undesired impression that the hand writing wasn't easily read.

Comment: Seriously? Someone came downvoting this after 2.3 years :D

Answer (score -1):

In America, if a note is sent in appreciation, it is often written on a **Thank You card**.

These are fold-out cards (similar to *Birthday Cards* or *Christmas Cards*, but maybe half the size.) They typically have a decorated front side preprinted with "Thank You" (or some variation), and a totally blank inside, in which the writer pens a short note. They are often sold in a pack of 10, 12, 20 or so, with little envelopes. Here's what they look like:

http://www.google.com/search?q=thank+you+card+images&client=safari&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ZAYlVfeZENGzoQSqq4C4CA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=320&bih=356